# input me da el valor de null en Java EE y PostgresSQL

Tags: java, html, postgresql, java-ee, servlets

ayuda ya he pasado de error en error con mi codigo y en todos el problema esta relacionado con "null", mi conclusion es que el input de mi form me da un valor null y no el que el que yo tecleo.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;        
public class insert extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
 {
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
boolean exito=false;
Connection con=null;
try
{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
  String nombre=request.getParameter("nombre");
  String url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBFormulario";
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","postgres");
  String query="INSERT INTO Formulario (nom) VALUES ("+nombre+");";
  out.println("Sentencia SQL: "+query);
  Statement inst=con.createStatement();
  inst.executeUpdate(query);
  con.close();
  inst.close();
  exito=true;
  out.println("<br>Conexion Exitosa a DBFormulario!!!<br>");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  out.println("<br>Hubo un problema !!!<br>"+e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
  out.println("<br>Hubo un problema !!!<br>"+e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
}
if (exito){
  out.println ("<h3> Los datos han sido enviados !!! </h3>");

out.println ("<h3><a href=http://127.0.0.1:8080/FORMULARIO/index.jsp>Regresa a capturar...</a></h3>");
out.close();}}}
```

Comment: Eso es muy fácil de saber, ¿por qué no depuras tu variable: `out.println(nombre);` o bien tu objeto completo: `out.println(request);` Otra cosa: en el `INSERT` usa comillas simples para los valores: `  String query="INSERT INTO Formulario (nom) VALUES ("'+nombre+'");"; En futuro considera implementar consultas preparadas, ya que esa consulta ejecutada así es una puerta abierta a la inyección SQL en tu código.

Comment: muchas gracias! por todo no sabia cuan era la diferencia de una consulta preparada, y mi error estaba en el form tenia una encriptacion que no permitia insertar correctamente.